# AngularJS : ng-repeat list not updating - directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular and I have the following code:

**Here is my html:**

```
<drawer title="'Add a new Item'"
         visible="showAddItemDrawer"
         on-close="showAddApplicationItem = false">
    <!-- items list refresh does not work from inside the drawer. -->
     <add-item></add-item> 
</drawer>
<!--list refresh works if i place the code out here.
    <add-item></add-item> -->

<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <item-list></item-list>
</div>
```

**Here is my directive.js:**

```
directive("additem", function () {
     return {
        restrict:"E",
        transclude:true,
        controller:"ItemsCtrl",
        templateUrl:"partials/add-item.html" //contains a form to add item
     };
})

.directive("itemlist", function () {
   return {
      restrict:"E",
      transclude:true,
      templateUrl:"partials/item-list.html" //contains code to display the items in a list
   };
})
```

I have a form in add-item.html to add an item. The form shows up when you click on add button(like an accordion). I call the push() to add a new item to the scope.

The list update works if i place the  directive call outside the drawer.. 
If i place it inside the drawer,the scope is not getting updated until i hit refresh.

Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong with the directives? Thanks a lot!

**Edit: Added additional code :**

**In the form to add an item:**

```
<button type="submit"
        ng-click="addItemService()">
    Add Item
</button>
```

**addItemService() code:**

```
$scope.addItemService = function () {
    var data = {
      "name": $scope.itemName,
     };
    ItemService.addItem(data, $scope.listgroupid)
       .success(function (result) {
            $scope.itemName = "";
            viewList(); //The function that sets the scope of the list
        })
        .error(function () {
        });
};
```

**viewlist() code:**

```
var viewList = function () {
   ListService.getList($scope.listgroupid)
       .success(function (result) {
           $scope.itemList = result;
           //In the angular inspector, I am able to see the new item in the variable result
       })
      .error(function () {
      });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: function scope is different from variable scope, use `$scope.$parent.itemList` when referencing new variable value

Comment: Tx.. But, I do have camelCase in my original code.. not here in the snippet.

Comment: so probably <code>$scope.$apply</code> problem... when you are manipulating with scope inside onClick handler, it is outside of the angulars digest cycle and you need to wrap scope manipulation in <code>$scope.$apply(function() { ... });</code>

Comment: ya i tried it first.. But, i got the digest already in progress error.I should add the $scope.$apply to the viewlist() function right?

Comment: addItemService function is defined in ItemsCtrl controller? If so, the itemList you are referencing in that function is defined on a different scope, than the scope used in ng-repeat (which is probably parent scope of the ItemsCtrl scope)

Comment: yes.. The addItemService() and viewList() are both defined in ItemsCtrl. So, how do i refer to something in a different scope? I dont understand why things would work if i place the directive call outside the drawer. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: you can access parent scope with <code>$scope.$parent.itemList</code> but preferred and recommended way of communicating between multiple controllers is via specific service... and as for different scopes - when directive with controller is on a deeper level from the rest of the code, I presume it creates it's own scope instead of using the one the rest of the code uses

Comment: or maybe the drawer directive creates isolated scope, that is also possible

Comment: Hurray!!! $scope.$parent.itemList works.. It updated the list.. Thanks..  Both the functions shown above are a part of the same controller.. Its just a view function thats reused in other calls..  I think the drawer is creating its own isolated scope.. In that case, is calling scope.parent fine? Could you point me to some example showing any other way.. Thanks a lot @doodeec ..

Comment: Can you add this as an answer instead of comment so that i can accept the answer? :)

Comment: I think it's fine to use $parent if you are using the function just in this context... but if you wanted to use the same directive multiple times in other parts of your application, it will be cleaner to use a service so it will me more reusable

Answer (score 1):

i had an issue where the directive scope (while debugging) and the batarang inspected scope (when selecting an element in the dev tools and typing $scope.varname in the console) were not matching after a successfully resolved promise.

the promise updates a list for a ng-repeat which contains a directive.

the debugged scope held the values from the last data before the promise was loading new data.

so i added a timeout around the data-loaded event broadcast which pushes the broadcast into the next digest cycle and angular gets informed about the update.
$scope.$apply most often throws the "apply already in progress" error.
the timeout solves this a little more softly...

```
$timeout( function () {
    // broadcast down to all directive children
    $scope.$broadcast('dataLoaded');
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

need to see the code wherein you are calling push for item.

In the absence of that I suspect this is scope issue. Remember that ngRepeat and drawer reside in difference scopes by default and until you have explicitly made them share certain variables , changes inside drawer won't be reflected in ngRepeat. For more on scopes inside directives read http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile.

> The 'isolate' scope takes an object hash which defines a set of local
>   scope properties derived from the parent scope. These local properties
>   are useful for aliasing values for templates. Locals definition is a
>   hash of local scope property to its source:
>
> @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM
>   attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are
>   strings. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is
>   assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localName:'@myAttr' },
>   then widget scope property localName will reflect the interpolated
>   value of hello {{name}}. As the name attribute changes so will the
>   localName property on the widget scope. The name is read from the
>   parent scope (not component scope).
>
> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value
>   of the attr attribute. If no attr name is specified then the attribute
>   name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: {
>   localModel:'=myAttr' }, then widget scope property localModel will
>   reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to
>   parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in
>   localModel will reflect in parentModel. If the parent scope property
>   doesn't exist, it will throw a NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION
>   exception. You can avoid this behavior using =? or =?attr in order to
>   flag the property as optional.
>
> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of
>   the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name
>   is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: {
>   localFn:'&myAttr' }, then isolate scope property localFn will point to
>   a function wrapper for the count = count + value expression. Often
>   it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression
>   and to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local
>   variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example,
>   if the expression is increment(amount) then we can specify the amount
>   value by calling the localFn as localFn({amount: 22}).

Comment: I have added the additional code. Thanks for your help.. When I debug using angular inspector in chrome, I am able to see the new value in the result variable getting added. Any ideas?

Comment: in batarang, can you check the models tab and see if the arrays inside the directive and inside ngRepeat are in same scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a $rootScope.$broadcast() to fire an event that your directive would capture, and then let the directive update the list with ng-repeat or you could call a $scope.$apply() with the updation wrapped in it within the controller to indicate angular that he list is updated, but when using $scope.$apply() be careful, and make sure it that it is delayed/deferred until the next digest cycle. 
A library called Underscore.js lets you delay $apply until the next digest cycle.